# How to add "?id=11" in URL in Yii framework?

Tags: url, yii

I need to add `?id=11` in url.I used `Yii::app()->createUrl('reviews')` yii function.I want to show URL which look like

```
http://localhost/mysite/reviews/?id=11
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Yii::app()->createUrl("reviews",array("id"=>11))
```

Comment: According to your suggestion it showing now http://localhost/mysite/reviews/id/11

Comment: @VinayakMali, it depends of your routing configuration, which can be found in main.php config file. You can edit routing rules to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.